# Bash : how to check if a column in a .csv file contains any text at all?

Tags: bash, csv, filter

how can I use bash to check a `.csv` file?  Example below.

```
Data,Time,Gender
015248,12:04,Male
054258,10.10,
025487,13:10,
012425,12.02,Female
```

All I want is a bash script to:

1. Open the .csv file.
2. If no data exists after the third `,`, delete that line.
3. If data does exist `,female`, keep the line.

Can anybody show me how to do this?  I have searched google but could not find anything that I understand.

Comment: It is worth having an #SOSearch before #FirstSOQuestion though ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 awk -F',' '{gsub(/^ +/,"",$3);if(length($3) != 0){OFS=",";print}}' your_csv_file.csv > tmp && mv tmp your_csv_file.csv
```

This will delete unwanted lines from the original file.

**Edit**

The `gsub(/^ +/,"",$3)` will check for any rogue spaces at the beginning of `$3` and remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sed` for this:

```
$ cat <<__EOT__ | sed -e '/,$/d'
> Data,Time,Gender
> 015248,12:04,Male
> 054258,10.10,
> 025487,13:10,
> 012425,12.02,Female
> __EOT__
Data,Time,Gender
015248,12:04,Male
012425,12.02,Female
```

Or, `sed -e '/,$/d' your_csv_file.csv`, if you prefer that. The sed line deletes all of the lines that end with a komma.

And if you want to do both nr. 1, 2 and 3 from your question (I read that as only print lines that end with `,Female`), use `sed -ne '/,Female$/p' your_csv_file.csv`. The `-n` says not to print the lines, the `/p` says to print the lines that match. You can add a `I` after the `p` to make the search case insensitive, but that only works on GNU sed (linux).